# Can a Homeomorphism exist between two discontinuous spaces.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In trying to solve a complex problem, I encountered a sub problem about homeomorphisms between level sets of functions. To explain the problem I have created a specific example pictured in a sketch below:
[image]

Additional information about the example:

- The black lines are level sets of some function which is defined for some space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for convenience the sketch is for $\mathbb{R}^2$). The red line is to indicate there is a discontinuity between the level sets between the two regions $V_{1,1}$ and $V_{2,1}$ (and the other two regions $V_{1,2}$ and $V_{2,2}$).
- Points on the red boundary belong to region $V_{2,1}$ (and $V_{2,2}$).
- There exists a homeomorphism between the level sets for regions $V_{1,1}$ and $V_{1,2}$, and a homeomorphism between the level sets for regions $V_{2,1}$ and $V_{2,2}$.

> My question is: With this discontinuity between $V_{1,1}$ and $V_{2,1}$ (or the other two regions $V_{1,2}$ and $V_{2,2}$) can there exist a homeomorphism between the two different level sets.

My concern is at the red boundary line and the open set definition of continuity, as I do not believe that open sets maps to open sets along this red boundary. On the other hand the existence of homeomorphisms for the different regions suggests that I could combine them to form a single homeomorphism.

Additional Notes

- If you have any additional questions I can provide needed clarification.

Comment: I think you should be a little more precise about exactly what data you're working with here. Not necessarily the details of the functions, but say we're given the functions as black boxes, what do you mean by homeomorphisms between the level sets? Do the two homeomorphisms agree on the boundary?

Comment: @jgon To answer your questions: The functions are Lyapunov functions, A homeomorphism between level sets of two Lyapunov function means the Lyapunov functions are topologically equivalent. I do not know the form of the Lyapunov function only their level sets (this is a common problem in dynamical systems). The two homeomorphisms are not defined at the boundary, as the example is written only the hoeomorphism between the level sets in regions $V_{2,1}$ to $V_{2,2}$ includes the red boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: in particular, if $V_{1,1} = V_{1,2}$ and $V_{2,1} = V_{2,2}$, then the identity is such a map, and is always a homeomorphism, without any assumptions on the nature of the space involved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For clarification $V_{1,1}=V_{1,2}$ means that these regions are topologically equivalent and not that they are identical. My sketch may have suggested they are identical so I have changed the sketch.

Comment: I just gave an example where it works, so for the purpose of my answer, they are literally the same set.

Comment: Okay does your example work if instead of $V_{1,1}$ being identical to $V_{1,2}$ and  $V_{2,1}$ being identical to $V_{2,2}$ they are topologically equivalent to each other?

Comment: Almost certainly, but there's some more work to be done to prove it: here, I'm using that the two homeomorphisms have a common extension to a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: That explanation make sense. Is there a straight forward way to extended these homeomorphisms to a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$? Again the concern is at the red boundary. As a point on the boundary belongs to $V_{2,1}$, an open set around this point is in both $V_{1,1}$ and $V_{2,1}$. Does this open set at the boundary map to open set given the existence of the two separate homeomorphisms?

Comment: @AzJ No, but the problem is essentially that you've chosen to put the boundary in your sets. If you take your sets to not include the boundary, then that issue goes away: their union is then not connected, and you can map either side separately without issue. Is there a particular reason that you need the boundary included?

Comment: Their is no particular reason, the method used to derive level sets extends up to the boundary. The boundary can be removed and be considered separately. Thanks again for your answer and further comments.